# convert chart from static data to chart from database data

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, function, charts

I have this function

```
    public ActionResult GetChartImage()
    {
        var key = new Chart(width: 300, height: 300)
            .AddTitle("Employee Chart")
            .AddSeries(
            chartType: "Bubble",
            name: "Employee",
            xValue: new[] { "Peter", "Andrew", "Julie", "Dave" },
            yValues: new[] { "2", "7", "5", "3" });

        return File(key.ToWebImage().GetBytes(), "image/jpeg");
    }
```

This creates a chart from static data.

If I had a database with a table named Employee and the features `Name` and `Satisfunction`.

**Question:** How could I tranform the function above to return a chart with dynamic data? I have no experience at all with C# and how it works.

Comment: I think it will be easy for you to use google chart https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery?hl=fr, its fast on the client side

Comment: I think `xValues` should be the array of the column `Name` values, and the same for `yValues`; the other column values

Comment: @brykneval Wow!!!! Thanks a lot brykneval!!! they are really beautiful and more interactive!!! thanks.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal thanks Mahmoud. But how I can do that?

Comment: Get the data from the database, then populate two arrays for each column values.

Comment: @brykneval Do you know any other similar thing for asp? Unfortunately for my project I need to use only Microsoft Technologies... But I want to make something beautiful and fancy

Comment: Also, look at [HighCharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/) it is a javascript-based charts library and it is very interactive and easy to customize.

Comment: @JohnSmith you can try as Mahmoud said, get value from database and populate in arrary or a dictionary and replace on xValues : array

Answer (score 1):

in action i have:

```
///Get data from db

var articles = _db.Articles
        .OrderByDescending(a => a.Visites)
        .Take(6)
        .ToList();

//create chart note xValue i m passing my articles as data to this
// xFiled witch is set to Title is a property on my article class

var chart = new Chart(520, 340, theme: ChartTheme.Blue)
            .AddTitle("Most visited articles")
            .AddSeries(name: "Default",
                xValue: articles, xField: "Title", chartType: "StackedColumn",
                yValues: articles, yFields: "Visites")
            .GetBytes("png");

        return File(chart, "image/png");
```

you may also look at [Displaying data in charts on asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/7-displaying-data-in-a-chart)